# How to handle missing data in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing the following information:

- For each Timestamp, there are a number of Trays (between 1-4) out of 8 available Trays. (So there is a maximum number of 4 Trays per Timestamp.)
- Each Tray consists of 4 positions.

A dataframe could look like this:

```
df = 

     timestamp    t_idx  position  error    type    SNR
 0   16229767       5        2       1       T1     123
 1   16229767       5        1       0       T1     123
 3   16229767       5        3       0       T1     123
 4   16229767       5        4       0       T1     123
 5   16229767       3        3       1       T9      38
 6   16229767       3        1       0       T9      38
 7   16229767       3        4       0       T9      38
 8   29767162       7        1       0       T4     991
 9   29767162       7        4       1       T4     991
```

If we look at the timestamp "16229767", there where 2 trays in use: Tray 3 and Tray 5.
Each position for Tray 5 was detected.
However, Tray 3 has missing data, as position 2 is missing.

I would like to fix that and add this line programmatically:

```
 10  16229767       3        2       1       T9      38

 11  29767162       7        2       1       T4     991 
 12  29767162       7        3       1       T4     991
```

I am not sure how to handle the missing values correctly. My naive approach right now is:

```
timestamps = df['timestamp'].unique()
for ts in timestamps:
    tray_ids = df.loc[df['timestamp'] == timestamps ]["Tray ID"].unique()
    for t_id in tray_ids:
        # For timestamp and tray id: Each position (1 to 4) should exist once!
        # df.loc[(df['timestamp'] == ts) & (df['Tray ID'] == t_id)] 
        # if not, append the position on the tray and set error to 1
```

How can I find the missing positions now and add the rows to my dataframe?

===

Edit:
I was simplifying my example, but missed a relevant information:
There are also other columns and the new generated rows should have the same content *per* tray. I made it clearer by adding to more columns.

Also, there was a question about the error: For each row that had to be added, the error should be automatically 1 (there is no logic behind).

Comment: You might try converting from long to wide format and back again.  The implicit missing values will become overt in wide format, if you see what I mean.

Comment: How the `error` value is set?

Comment: kindly provide the expected output dataframe

Comment: @Corralien, the error should always be 1 for every new added line.

Comment: @sammywemmy, how exactly can I help with that? I mentioned a expected result in my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start by converting `position` to the categorical type, use a `groupby` to fill all the missing values and set the corresponding `error` values to `1`.
We also have to fill the `type` and `SNR` column with the correct values like so :

```py
>>> df['position'] = pd.Categorical(df['position'], categories=df['position'].unique())
>>> df_grouped = df.groupby(['timestamp', 't_idx', 'position'], as_index=False).first()
>>> df_grouped['error'] = df_grouped['error'].fillna(1)

>>> df_grouped.sort_values('type', inplace=True)
>>> df_grouped['type'] = df_grouped.groupby(['timestamp','t_idx'])['type'].ffill().bfill()

>>> df_grouped.sort_values('SNR', inplace=True)
>>> df_grouped['SNR'] = df_grouped.groupby(['timestamp','t_idx'])['SNR'].ffill().bfill()

>>> df_grouped = df_grouped.reset_index(drop=True)
    timestamp   t_idx   position    error   type    SNR
0   16229767    3       1           0.0     T9      38.0
1   16229767    3       3           1.0     T9      38.0
2   16229767    3       4           0.0     T9      38.0
3   16229767    5       2           1.0     T1      123.0
4   16229767    5       1           0.0     T1      123.0
5   16229767    5       3           0.0     T1      123.0
6   16229767    5       4           0.0     T1      123.0
7   29767162    7       1           0.0     T4      991.0
8   29767162    7       4           1.0     T4      991.0
9   16229767    3       2           1.0     T9      38.0
10  16229767    7       2           1.0     T4      991.0
11  16229767    7       1           1.0     T4      991.0
12  16229767    7       3           1.0     T4      991.0
13  16229767    7       4           1.0     T4      991.0
14  29767162    3       2           1.0     T4      991.0
15  29767162    3       1           1.0     T4      991.0
16  29767162    3       3           1.0     T4      991.0
17  29767162    3       4           1.0     T4      991.0
18  29767162    5       2           1.0     T4      991.0
19  29767162    5       1           1.0     T4      991.0
20  29767162    5       3           1.0     T4      991.0
21  29767162    5       4           1.0     T4      991.0
22  29767162    7       2           1.0     T4      991.0
23  29767162    7       3           1.0     T4      991.0
```

And then, we filter on the value from the original `DataFrame` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df_grouped[
...     pd.Series(
...         list(zip(df_grouped['timestamp'].values, df_grouped['t_idx'].values))
...     ).isin(list(zip(df['timestamp'].values, df['t_idx'].values)))
... ].sort_values(by=['timestamp', 't_idx']).reset_index(drop=True)
    timestamp   t_idx   position    error   type    SNR
0   16229767    3       1           0.0     T9      38.0
1   16229767    3       3           1.0     T9      38.0
2   16229767    3       4           0.0     T9      38.0
3   16229767    3       2           1.0     T9      38.0
4   16229767    5       2           1.0     T1      123.0
5   16229767    5       1           0.0     T1      123.0
6   16229767    5       3           0.0     T1      123.0
7   16229767    5       4           0.0     T1      123.0
8   29767162    7       1           0.0     T4      991.0
9   29767162    7       4           1.0     T4      991.0
10  29767162    7       2           1.0     T4      991.0
11  29767162    7       3           1.0     T4      991.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I like this solution, but missed some information in my inital question and am wondering if this solution would be easy to fix?

Comment: I saw that you changed the initial data in your question, so I reworked the answer to get everything right. Hope it helps ;) !

Answer (score 1):

[pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) has a [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function that exposes explicitly missing values ([pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) is a collection of convenient Pandas functions);

In the challenge above, only the explicitly missing values within the data needs to be exposed:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df.complete(['timestamp', 't_idx', 'type', 'SNR'], 'position')
   .fillna({"error":1}, downcast='infer')
   .filter(df.columns)
)
 
    timestamp  t_idx  position  error type  SNR
0    16229767      5         2      1   T1  123
1    16229767      5         1      0   T1  123
2    16229767      5         3      0   T1  123
3    16229767      5         4      0   T1  123
4    16229767      3         2      1   T9   38
5    16229767      3         1      0   T9   38
6    16229767      3         3      1   T9   38
7    16229767      3         4      0   T9   38
8    29767162      7         2      1   T4  991
9    29767162      7         1      0   T4  991
10   29767162      7         3      1   T4  991
11   29767162      7         4      1   T4  991
```

In the code above, just the the combination of `['timestamp', 't_idx', 'type', 'SNR']` and `position` is required to generate the missing values, limiting the output to only the explicit missing values *within* the dataframe; if all combinations of missing values were required, then the brackets would be dropped, and you'd probably get a much larger dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dataframe with the timestamp with fixed range of position. Then you merge them together and you will end up with NaN values on errors columns for given missing position. Then you fill the NaN to 1.

Sample code:

```
unique_id = df.timestamp.unique().tolist()
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':unique_id,'position':range(4)})
df = pd.merge(df_tmp, df, on=["timestamp", "position"], how="left")
df.error.fillna(1)
```

Comment: The second line is throwing an error: "ValueError: arrays must all be same length". Note also the slightly changed question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```py
def foo(df):
    set_ = set(range(1,5))
    if df.position.unique().size < 4:
        diff_ = set_.difference(df.position.unique())
        add_df = df.iloc[:len(diff_),:].copy()
        add_df.loc[:, 'position'] = list(diff_)
        # I did not understand by what rule the values in the error column are set. You can install it as you need
        result_df = pd.concat([df, add_df], ignore_index=True)
        return result_df
    else: 
        return df

group = df.groupby(['timestamp', 't_idx'])
group.apply(foo)
```

```
    timestamp   t_idx   position    error
0   16229767     3        3           1
1   16229767     3        1           0
2   16229767     3        4           0
3   16229767     3        2           1
4   16229767     5        2           1
5   16229767     5        1           0
6   16229767     5        3           0
7   16229767     5        4           0
8   29767162     7        1           0
9   29767162     7        4           1
10  29767162     7        2           0
11  29767162     7        3           1
```

Comment: Seems like the 'if' is never been executed, since my dataset contains all possible positions.